# Changes made to individuals using Contact Editor not showing up

Tags: contacts

I'm using Wordpress and recently upgraded to CiviCRM version 4.6.3. Since I have the editor for individual contacts has ceased to save changes. When viewing an individual contact, I can edit fields using the in-line editors, but when I click the "EDIT" button and edit from the contact editor and click "SAVE", I get a message saying the contact has been updated but the new information is nowhere to be found! The editor does work for households and organizations though.

I did duplicate this on the demo site.

Comment: I have the IDENTICAL problem in CiviCRM 4.7.31 running up-to-date WordPress v 4.9.6 Is there somewhere I can go to find a solution? Two years seems to be quite a long time for a critical issue like this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this problem has already been reported and a bug report has been made. I didn't realize it at first but it is the same problem as Maurice's, edits are not saved using the editor form when "use another address" option is checked. Individuals without that option checked can still be edited. I guess I'm just confirming that the problem exists in Wordpress as well.

Comment: Could you please provide the Jira link?